# IIS: missing configuration/properties

Tags: iis-7

In IIS (Windows Server 2008) I open the IIS Manager, then expand the local server name, the expand "Sites" and right click on "Default Web Site" but no "Properties" show up.

According [to this Microsoft article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d29207e8-5274-4f4b-9a00-9433b73252d6.mspx?mfr=true), that is where I would go to find the logging options (which I need to turn on).

What am I missing? I can stop or start "Default Web Site" no problem. The right click menu only brings up:

- Explore
- Edit Permissions
- Add Application
- Add Virtual Directory
- Edit Bindings
- Manage Web Site -> Restart/Start/Stop/Browser, Advanced Settings (no Logging tab)
- Refresh
- Remove
- Rename
- Switch to Content View

Under the Features View, I don't see Logging either. I see:

- .NET Auth
- .NET Compilation
- .NET Error Pages
- .NET Globalization
- .NET Trust Levels
- Application Settings
- Connection Strings
- SMTP E-mail
- Authentication
- Handler Mappings
- HTTP Responses
- Modules
- Output Caching
- Request Filtering
- SSL Settings
- Configuration Editor

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds as if you've not installed any of the logging elements of the Health and Diagnostics IIS Role Service:

[image]

You need to install at least the "HTTP Logging" role service for the Logging feature to appear.

Comment: Somehow I completely missed this, thanks for pointing out the obvious, heh. Sometimes we just need to be pointed to it.

Answer (score 1):

That context menu you list is clearly not IIS6, but IIS 7.0.

When you choose a web site in the left pane, the "Feature View" should open in the middle pane, here is a feature option called "Logging", denoted by a notepad-like icon.

Depending on whether you need to configure the "default" logging settings (on server-level) or logging for a specific site, read one of the articles listed here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732079(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: My bad, I read "Version 6.1" under Help-About in IIS but that appears to represent the OS?

Comment: I checked the Feature View and see no Logging. See my question for the edit.

Comment: Check the Web Server Role in Server Manager on the machine, and make sure that the logging feature is installed